# Change styles based on title name

Tags: javascript

I am working on a site and need to only show a div if the title = "something". I cannot seem to achieve it, I have tried jQuery and javascript, here is what I have now.

```
var title = document.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].innerHTML;
    console.log(title);
    document.getElementsByClassName("book-a-lane").elems[0].style.visibility=     "hidden";
    if(title === "Frisco, TX"){
    document.getElementsByClassName("book-a-lane").elems[0].style.visibility= "block";
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get the title much more easily via `document.title`.

You're inventing a property here:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("book-a-lane").elems[0]
// --------------------------------------------^^^^^
```

`getElementsByClassName` returns a list, it doesn't have an `elems` property. Also note that `getElementsByClassName` isn't as well supported as `querySelector`, which would be more useful here.

You can also simplify the code dramatically.

Here's an example:

```
document.querySelector(".book-a-lane").style.visibility =
  document.title === "Frisco, TX" ? "visible" : "hidden";
```

`querySelector` takes a CSS selector and returns the first matching element (or `null`). There's also `querySelectorAll`, which returns a list of matching elements.

You might want `document.title.trim()`, but beware browser support for it.

[Live example when it matches.](http://jsbin.com/pinilo)

[Live example when it doesn't.](http://jsbin.com/buwapa)

Answer (score 0):

The `title` variable's value can be fetched with this: `var title = document.title`.

The line inside your `if` statement is faulty because there's no such thing as `visibility: block;`. It's either `display: block;` or `visibility: visible;`.

This is the semi-improved version:

```
var title = document.title;
document.getElementsByClassName("book-a-lane")[0].style.visibility = "hidden";
if (title == "Frisco, TX") {
    document.getElementsByClassName("book-a-lane")[0].style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

You don't need to use `.elms` to access the elements.

You can even use the `?` strategy to do a true/false switch:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("book-a-lane")[0].style.visibility = title == "Frisco, TX" ? "visible": "hidden";
```

Comment: This throws Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined

Comment: That's weird! What if the spec changed? All the web-apps using the array index accessor will be broken!

Comment: I searched on Google for the `elms` thing but nothing shows up that's actually real, so you must've defined `elms` somewhere.

Comment: @JerryLee That error will be returned if there is no element with that class.

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean to do this?

```
var title = document.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].innerHTML;

document.getElementsByClassName("book-a-lane")[0].style.visibility="hidden";

if(title === "Frisco, TX"){
    document.getElementsByClassName("book-a-lane")[0].style.visibility= "block";
}
```

Notice the lack of `elems`. `getElementsByClassName` can be accessed with the array accessor directly.

Comment: It's throwing this in the console:  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: Sorry I edited my answer, I wrote it wrongly the first time.

Comment: I don't know why it keeps throwing this error in console: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined